# Beyond Compare: Copy automatically text from one file to another

Tags: beyondcompare

I am using Beyond Compare and there I try to copy text from one file to another. The problem is, I many thousand lines...

Always, when there is a line, which starts with the tag `<target state="translated">` I want to copy it automatically to the right. If I do it manually, it works, but it will take my hours to do this in that manner...

So do you have an idea, how to manage that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Beyond Compare doesn't provide a way to automatically copy lines that start with a specific tag. Copying lines between sides is always a manual process.